# Why does volley always send another packet 5 minutes after the last packet is sent?

Tags: ssl, tcp, android-volley, wireshark, packet

I have an android app that sends a request to the server via Volley.
The communication is fine but I see unnecessary packets(no.385 ~ no.387) as below. These packets are always sent 5 minutes after the last packet is sent. Please let me know why the client sends the packets to the server and how I can avoid sending these packets.

client : 10.x.x.x
server : 52.x.x.x

Packets 385-387 are relevant here:
[image of my wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtQng.png)